# Cartesian position node

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using tf and an ik solver which offers two services: get_ik and get_fk (that's supposed to be generic).
Is there a node that can subscribe to tf, use get_fk and publish on a "cartesian pose" topic? And another for the inverse calculation (ie subscribe to cartesian pose, do get_ik, and publish to tf). I could create one, but this seems like a standard procedure.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75919/cartesian-position-node/) by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard for FK would be do use a URDF for the kinematics description, publish joint angles, and then run the robot_state_publisher, which will publish all FK transformations via tf.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on 2013-09-02**:
Thanks for the input. However I thought the robot_state_publisher was publishing joint angles to the tf, which then handles the FK (you can access the FK by calling rosrun tf tf_echo /base_joint /end_effector).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-02**:
It's the other way around. robot_state_publisher receives joint angles and produces tf. FK handling is done in the robot_state_publisher.